# How to lauch APK installation from notification?

Tags: android, notifications, apk

Hello :) I want to launch APK installation by clicking the notification. I have already implemented file download and after that notification appears but if I click on such notification.... nothing happens. Here is my code for the notification

```
    private fun showUpdateReadyToInstallNotification(file: File) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "UPDATE_CHANNEL")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Update")
        .setContentText("Your Update is Downloaded and ready to install! Press This notification to install")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("UPDATE_CHANNEL", "Update", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    notificationManager.notify(100, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Comment: You can not call implicit intents from the Notification service or Pending Intents, Probably you have to call your own activity or receiver to do this installation stuff. Open any activity or receiver after clicking on notification and it will work.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. I found what was wrong... I gave permission "INSTALLIG_PACKAGES" and "DELETE_PACKAGES" but what I need was "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"... after I had added that permission entry to manifest everything started to work... even mine solution ;p Thank You for You time